# Load next item of reyclerview when user clicks on next button, having error in this

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am making an android app in which i have reyclerview whenever user clicks on recyclerview items then he is navigating to next activity and in next activity data will be shown. It is working but now i am adding next and previous button in it. Whenever next button will be clicked then next reycler items'data should be shown and same with previous button.

But i am getting error in this. It is my code.

RecylerAdapter:

```
public class ContentViewRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<ContentModel>contentModels;
Context context;

public ContentViewRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ContentModel> contentModels, Context context) {
    this.contentModels = contentModels;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ContentViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContentViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(contentModels.get(position).getContent());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ContentViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("valuecontent", contentModels.get(position).getContent());
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("contentmodels", contentModels);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contentModels.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
    }
}
```

}

ModelClass:

```
public class ContentModel implements Parcelable {
String content;

public ContentModel(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

protected ContentModel(Parcel in) {
    content = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ContentModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ContentModel>() {
    @Override
    public ContentModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ContentModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ContentModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ContentModel[size];
    }
};

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(content);
}
```

}

ContentViewActivity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_view);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView_content);
    next = findViewById(R.id.next);
    prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.backbtncntent);
    sharebtn = findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
    copybtn = findViewById(R.id.copy);
    contentModels = new ArrayList<>();
    contentModels.clear();
    contentModels = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("contentmodels");
    final String valuecontent = getIntent().getStringExtra("valuecontent");
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
    textView.setText((Integer) contentModels.get(position));
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ContentViewActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    sharebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hey Read Some Interesting Content");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, valuecontent);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
        }
    });
    copybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setClipboard(ContentViewActivity.this,textView.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position =(position+1)%contentModels.size();
            textView.setText((Integer) contentModels.get(position));
        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position =(position-1)%contentModels.size();
            textView.setText((Integer) contentModels.get(position));
        }
    });
}
private void setClipboard(Context context, String text) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(text);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text);
        Toast.makeText(ContentViewActivity.this, "Copied to Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

}

The error i am getting:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: example.example1.shayariapp.Models.ContentModel cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at example.example1.shayariapp.Acitivties.ContentViewActivity.onCreate(ContentViewActivity.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7227)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7218)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2941)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:202) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6962) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Please please help me to solve this issue. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located here:

`textView.setText((Integer) contentModels.get(position));`

You are trying to parse `ContentModel` item into `Integer`.

You are doing this 3 times. Inside `onCreate()` and inside `ClickListeners` for `next` and `prev`.

Comment: What should i write ? Please tell me right code. I want to set text to textview from contentmodels according to position.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to display there. The only field your class does have is `String content` so if you want to display it inside `TextView` you can just do `textView.setText( contentModels.get(position).getContent());`. There is no need to parse anything.

Comment: i want to display text....but contentModels.get(position).getContent() is not accessible from Activity.

Comment: You have `contentModels = new ArrayList<>(); contentModels.clear();` inside your `onCreate()` so it is there, and `getContent()` is public, so where is the problem?